# MSSQL services not starting

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have two questions

First question:
I am using MSSQL 2008 R2 database.I tried starting but the  MSSQL service not start.I installed MSSQL program again and the problem is solved.But I want to know the cause of this problem.What is the reason for not starting SQL?

Second question:

One of my tables corruptioned.The error is as follows.

**Attempt to fetch logical page (1:616) in database 5 failed. It belongs to allocation unit 72057594066763776 not to 72057594064142336.**

what could be the reason for this?

Comment: Scan your hard drive for corruption Google "CHKDSK", then check database for corruption (see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-checkdb-transact-sql )

Comment: "Attempt to fetch logical page (1:616) in database 5 failed. It belongs to allocation unit 72057594066763776 not to 72057594064142336."   What is this error?Can you tell me plz

Comment: I am not 100% sure but it looks like some sort of data corruption either at the hard drive level or DB level, hence my first comment to check your HDD and DB for corruption

Comment: check event log and check error log and test drive corruption.

Comment: Your second part may be due to an issue with the database page or a problem with the SQL Server engine when determining what the expected allocation unit should be. See the Resolution section for more details.